# Windows Performance Recorder

Tags: windows, performance, visual-studio, recorder

I'm developing a windows driver. For doing this I use visual studio and WDK.

Now, I need to profile the code to find bottlenecks in the implementation.
I'm using the Windows Performance Recorder for this task.

The process I follow is very easy
I start the Trace Recorder and grab some information. Once I finish I save it on the hard drive. Then I open it up in WPA for analysis.

The thing is that when I run the tool on my machine it shows a few items under "Computation"

Two related to CPU Usage that I'm interested in
1) CPU Usage (Sampled).
2) CPU Usage(Precise).

[image]

So far so good. The problem I have is that when I run the same test in a machine that has the stand alone installer of this tools, instead of the one that comes with the SDKs and Visual Studio, the CPU Sample is never captured. It only shows the CPU Usage (Precise)

If someone knows how I can configure it to have these items correctly, it would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: How do you start tracing? If it is not displayed then the data was not recorded in the first place. Since there is no smiley of WPA I guess you are using the WDK for Windows 8 or 8.1? It should work since Windows 7 on which OS are you capturing the data?

Comment: - I open Windows Performance Recorder as amdmin.
- Check "Resources Analysis" -> "CPU Usage"
- Performance scenario = General
- Detail level = Verbose
- Logging Mode = Memory

Yes I'm using WDK for Windows 8.1.
And I'm running on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Do you have any Intel tools running on that machine? Like Intel Performance Counter Monitor or RealTemp which uses it under the hood as well? If yes disable these tools and restart the machine. It seems that specific instructions used by PCM break profiling.

Comment: Alois, yes, in fact the driver itself hooks to Performance Counters to track some events. I removed the driver and now the item appears. :-(

It seems it is not possible to use them both together. Do you know some other tool I could use (like a library or something) to do the same Job?

I will give a try to Intel VTune to see if it works.

Comment: You could notify Intel and MS support about the incompatiblity. Perhaps they can sort something out. Not sure which CPU instructions cause it. PCM library does a lot init. Perhaps it works if not all parts of PCM are initialized by default.

Comment: Cool, thank you for your help :-)